# How to show a progress counter while a xhttp object fetch data from XML?

Tags: javascript, xml, html, xmlhttprequest

I have a HTML page with a script, where a xhttp object reads node values from a XML file and writes them. Until all required nodes are read, I want to show a numeric progress indicator in percentage `(read_rows/total_rows * 100)`. But since the entire thing runs on one thread I can not accomplish this. Any suggestion to what I should do?

Here's some of the javascript code-

```
function fetch(xml_file, index) {

    //create xhttp object, read xml, get nodeValue of element "VALUE" etc...

    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET", xml_file ,false);
    xhttp.send(null);
    xmlDoc = xhttp.responseXML;
    data = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("VALUE")[index].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    document.write(data);

    // CALCULATE PROGRESS AND WRITE TO SOME OVERLAY DIV...

}
```

Here's a portion of the HTML-

```
<p><script>fetch(data_file, index); index++;</script></p>
<p><script>fetch(data_file, index); index++;</script></p>
<p><script>fetch(data_file, index); index++;</script></p>
```

As every `<p></p>` gets filled, I want to show the progress somewhere, say an overlay DIV. How do I do that simultaneously?

Comment: You could pass a callback function to fetch and use that to report progress.

Comment: Or make the request async and listen for progress events. You will have to deal with possibly incomplete elements though...

Comment: Your code will not work, xhttp.send is an asynchronous method, you need use `onreadystatechange`

Comment: Callback function worked perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using callback function I could display the progress while the xhttp object read data from the XML file.

I've changed the code to-

```
function fetch(xml_file, index) {

    //create xhttp object, read xml, get nodeValue of element "VALUE" etc...

    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET", xml_file ,false);
    xhttp.send(null);
    xmlDoc = xhttp.responseXML;
    data = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("VALUE")[index].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    document.write(data);

    progress(index); //CALLBACK FUNCTION

}

function progress(index) {
    document.getElementById("ProgressString").innerHTML = Math.round((index/358)*100) + "% complete"; // 358 nodes were to be read
}
```